# Linking Admob to Firebase

Tags: firebase, admob

I have created a project in firebase. I have also added an app in Admob with two banner ads. When I try to link this app to Firebase project, it always gives me this error :

> Unable to link app to Firebase. Please refresh the page and try again.

I tried refreshing the page and link the firebase project but no luck. It suggests me the firebase projects to choose in the dropdown, but when I try to link to a specific project, it doesn't allow me to link.

Comment: Hey, I dropped a more detailed answer below, but just so everyone sees it, you're welcome to report any issues like this to Firebase support: https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: @RedBrogdon Thanks for the answer. I think you are spot on with your answer. I ended up using different accounts - won't deny but it was painful.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get a solution working. You're not the only person to run into this kind of issue, and Firebase engineering is chasing down these edge cases..

Comment: Go to this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487410/admob-and-firebase/44587464#44587464

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error you're seeing,

```
Unable to link app to Firebase. Please refresh the page and try again.
```

is the base case message, unfortunately. It means that an unusual error has occurred, one so uncommon that it doesn't have a message of its own.

One reason we *have* seen it come up for people is that they've linked their AdMob app to a Firebase project, then deleted that project without unlinking it. This leaves the AdMob app tied to the dead project and unable to be linked to a new one. If that might be the case for your app, try this workaround:

1. Log into the Google Cloud Console (http://console.developers.google.com/)
2. Restore your project from deletion by using the steps listed here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787
3. Unlink that project from your AdMob app using these steps: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6387949
4. Link your AdMob app to a new project as normal.

Comment: Wow thank you you saved me several hours! This is not at all intuitive and such behaviour could have been hadled by Google..

Comment: Perfect!  Works like a charm.

Comment: @RedBrogdon unfortunately my grace period over and i couldn't restore the old project to unlink it. is there any other workaround?

Comment: @RedBrogdon, would you be so kind as to take a look at my question below. I feel like I'm stuck in a while loop :-/ - thank you!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898690/un-linking-firebase-app-from-admob-app

Answer (score 1):

typically this happens if the project owner in Firebase is not the same user as the AdMob user trying to do the linking.

Comment: I have the same issue and I'm using same account for both Firebase and Admob.

Comment: Yeah. Me too. Using the same account but still the error persists. I have written to the firebase support team and waiting for the resolution. Will write here once I get something on this.

Comment: @droidx did you get it resolved? I'm facing the same issue here

Comment: @Sreekanth The answer/steps provided by RedBrogdon (accepted above) should help solve the issue.