# Unable to link app to Firebase. Please refresh the page and try again

Tags: android, firebase, admob, firebase-analytics

1. I've a Firebase project for Android app on Account 1.
2. The app is published on google play developer account linked to Account 1.
3. Now I want to show ads in the app.
4. I already have Admob account with another Google Account. ie Account 2.
   So I added that account as "owner" in firebase project settings from Account 1.
   Now both Account 1 and Account 2 are owners of the firebase project.
5. When I tried to create a ad unit (from Account 2) and link to firebase project It said "Unable to link app to Firebase. Please refresh the page and try again."
   It kept on saying the same after several attempts. So I decided to try different route.
6. I created a new Admob account with Account 1 and tried to create and link firebase project from that account. But again it said "Unable to link app to Firebase. Please refresh the page and try again."

I've found here ([Linking Admob to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37543240/linking-admob-to-firebase)) saying to unlink already linked admob account from firebase project and try again. But I don't see any Admob accounts linked to my firebase project when checked. In fact I didn't find an option to "View your linked apps" in the "Account Linking" tab. It just has links to sdks and documentations.

So now I have 2 Admob accounts, 1 firebase project and no admob accounts linked to the project. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be great if down voters mention the reason so that I can rectify or improve .

Comment: Have you try contacting Firebase support ? https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ They might be able to give you a better explanation and fix as they will be able to look into your project configuraton.

Comment: Yes. I've contacted them. Waiting for reply. It's been two days