# How to grant Firebase Analytics permission in Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, admob, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

All.

I have a question how to grant Firebase Analytics permission to another Admob account as following link.
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6376659?hl=en

Where can I find the screen? I could not find any ways to do this.

Also, I already completed the job explained as below to grant Firebase Analytics permission to another AdMob account.

[Add a user to your AdMob account] : Admob help page

-Grant the user access to the AdSense account associated with the Google Account you use to sign in to AdMob. The user must have an access level of Standard user or higher.

-Grant the user access to the AdWords account associated with the Google Account you use to sign in to AdMob. The user must have an access level of Standard user or higher.

But, When I sign in Admob site using the another account and click the analytics button, the message is displayed.

> You don't have access to Firebase Analytics from this AdMob account. 
>   Another user on this AdMob account has already obtained access to Firebase Analytics. Please ask that user to provide you with access to Firebase Analytics through the Firebase console. Learn more

[image]

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: Looks like it's already linked.

Comment: How to Link Admob to firebase:
Read In Deatil from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487410/admob-and-firebase/44587464#44587464

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

In Firebase console, click on Settings (the little wheel beside 'Overview'), then authorization. This will list all the accounts. Add the account you use for AdMob.