# Un-linking Firebase App from AdMob App

Tags: android, firebase, admob, adsense

I have a project/app in **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)** which is currently linked to it's corresponding [AdMob](https://www.google.co.uk/admob/) app.

Unfortunately, a series of bizarre events has led to my AdMob account being inaccessible.  My AdSense account is fine. (Actually, my AdMob account is still working it's just that I can't log into it).

AdSense/AdMob support have advised me that I need to delete my AdMob/AdSense accounts and then set up other accounts under a new email address.

However, in order to delete my AdMob account, I need to first [remove the link between Firebase and AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6273540?hl=en-GB), which isn't possible because I can't log into AdMob...

Would be grateful for any suggestions

Comment: Please indicate when you cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/IL_nMxMz7GQ

Comment: Apologies @FrankvanPuffelen, I wasn't aware that posting to non-stack sites was considered X-posting.I read this before I posted: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126920/does-a-dupe-on-another-non-se-so-site-warrant-a-vote-to-close (2nd paragraph of accepted answer). If this is incorrect information, I will take this into account next time I X-post - cheers.

Comment: If you're posting the same question in multiple locations, it is considered good form to indicate so. That way somebody willing to help can check if you've already been helped in the other location, before spending time.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6387949?hl=en#unlink

Currently, linking and unlinking can only be done in AdMob after sign in to your account.

Maybe deleting your admob account can able to automatically unlink your firebase, but i'm not sure in that. So please concern with their team and stackoverflow is not a place to non coding related topics.

Comment: Please feel free to migrate this question to a more appropriate Stack Exchange site @CamBarkRo.

Comment: Then you should use this link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk